# Android Map View v/s Web View?

Tags: android, maps

I am confused between webview and mapview, which is better?? in terms of flexibility, overlays, usage, load-speed, zoom levels etc etc

Comment: what do you mean ? both are use for diff way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MapView is the native built-in class for doing Map related stuff. WebView is a native element for the browser. It has a javascript to Java bridge, so you can call Java methods in your native Android application from the JavaScript page.

For my personal experience:

- WebView is less flexible, kinda sluggish for UI interaction.
- MapView has better optimizations and has richer content.
- MapView has definitely better caching.
- MapView loads faster (imo)
- The MapView api's make life much easier. Zooming/handling etc is great.

Though if you are good at JavaScript and the V3 you should go for WebView. It all boils down to the feature set (WebView has a larger feature set, or so I've heard) that you want to use, your project duration (MapView is faster and easier to code for)

Comment: is better ? mm.. how you can pass this urls , 2 examples :  first --- > "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?
       ll=36.97,%20-122&lci=bike&z=13&t=p&size=500x500&sensor=true" second ---- > https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=zeU8M-wjwMo0.kbwrypXJeOM8

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 classes are completely different.

The `WebView` class is there to show a webpage, the `MapView` class is there to intergrate Google Maps into your application. So depending on what you want to achieve you can pick one.

Since your tags say Google and Maps you should use the `MapView`, see also the [Google Map View](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) tutorial on the Android Developers site.

--

for future questions please provide some more information in your question.